# This site can’t provide a secure connection adbc.com sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: ssl, web

When I try to invoke a get request via URL in the browser (no matter what the browser is), this is the response I got.

Comment: This site is not listening in HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error has was given because my request is an http request where the service deployed in the server uses https (deployed in an  https port)